# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. While Adding items to Cart using Session in Asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

Hello Everyone I am trying to add items to cart using Session But I am facing That issue
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
[Check This Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qomzG.png)

Here is my View Where I want to show Cart items

```
 @foreach (var item in (List<Product>)Session["MyCart"])
                    {
                        
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="photo"><img src="@Url.Content(item.Product_Picture)" class="cart-thumb" alt="" /></a>
                            <h6><a href="#">@item.Product_Name </a></h6>
                            <p>1x -Rs <span class="price">@item.Product_SalePrice</span></p>
                        </li>
                     
                    }
                </ul>
```

Now This is my Action Controller

```
public ActionResult AddtoCart(int id)
    {
        List<Product> list;
        if (Session["MyCart"] == null)
        { list = new List<Product>(); }
        else
        { list = (List<Product>)Session["MyCart"]; }
        list.Add(db.Products.Where(p => p.Product_ID == id).FirstOrDefault());
        Session["MyCart"] = list;
        return RedirectToAction("Shop");
    }
```

Comment: When do you get this error? Is it on the `AddToCart` event or during the initialization of the original view?

Comment: initialization of original view

Comment: Can you show us that `Controller` code?

Comment: Which Code ??? Can you Explain Then I will Show you

Comment: The code when you initialize your `View`. It might be `ActionResult Index` ?

Comment: SUre Let me Share with you

Comment: This is my Controller Code

public ActionResult AddtoCart(int id)
        {
   List<Product> list;
   if (Session["MyCart"] == null)
   { list = new List<Product>(); }
   else
   { list = (List<Product>)Session["MyCart"]; }
   list.Add(db.Products.Where(p => p.Product_ID == id).FirstOrDefault());
   Session["MyCart"] = list;
   return RedirectToAction("Shop");
  }

Comment: What is your `View` name on which you are getting this error?

Comment: public class HomeController : Controller
 {
  Model1 db = new Model1();
  public ActionResult Indexcustomer()
  {
   return View();
  }

Comment: Here it is This one

Comment: Actually I am Add Foreach loop in _Layout Page to add Cart items in Side menu 
So When I Run the Project on every view it show the same error

Comment: Why are you doing that on your `_Layout` page? You should create a partial view for your carts and then refer it where it is required

Comment: Thanks Soo much Rahul Your Given Code Solved The Problem
But Can you Tell Me How to create a Partial view ??/ Because I am Fresh in Aps.net
Thanks Again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if your `Session` is not null on your `View` before you try to cast it and access its properties:

```
@if(Session["MyCart"] != null)
{
    foreach (var item in (List<Product>)Session["MyCart"])
    {
        
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="photo"><img src="@Url.Content(item.Product_Picture)" class="cart-thumb" alt="" /></a>
            <h6><a href="#">@item.Product_Name </a></h6>
            <p>1x -Rs <span class="price">@item.Product_SalePrice</span></p>
        </li>
     
    }
    </ul>
}
else
{
    <h2>Cart is empty</h2>
}
```

You should create a partial view for your carts and then refer it where it is required. There are many tutorial for partial views creation and usage You can refer to this [tutorial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/different-ways-of-render-partial-view-in-mvc/)